# What are some good resources for learning json?

Tags: c#, .net, json

does anyone know of any good resources for learning JSON? And preferably, if it even matters, from a .NET point of view? It seems like there aren't any straight forward resources for learning it yet its obviously used extensively (facebook api and twitter api and many, many more). I know I'm not the only one with this question so I'm sure many would benefit from any answers posted.

Thanks.

Comment: JSON is easy to learn; the JSON home page should be more than enough for that. Perhaps you meant "JSON handling" instead?

Comment: Try one of the frameworks like [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/). It's a good way to get your feet wet.

Comment: I guess..to be honest I'm not sure. I've been using xml, text..and have been avoiding json because of its lack of quality resources. But obviously it is being used more and I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could share how they mastered using json.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is invaluable while you are learning but won't help you learn directly.

Comment: @Michael Todd that looks very promising. I'm checking it out.

Comment: @havoc this is an excellent tool. I tried it and it works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most thorough resource is the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).  That is reasonable to read, but has good examples and will fill in the small gaps left in those tutorials.  It does include a little you can probably gloss over, like how to auto-detect the Unicode encoding.

The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is also good now.

Make sure you also look into [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), which is a way of padding JSON with a JavaScript function call to get around same-domain restrictions.

Comment: the wikipedia article has certaily changed from when I last saw it. Got's alot of good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.json.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON